# changerole() missing one required postional argument

Tags: python

```
**rolelist=["Auntie Lucy","Phua Chu Kang","Liang Popo"] 
  def changerole(roles,roleindex,replacement): 
           print("Original role to replace: ",rolelist[roleindex]) 
           rolelist[roleindex]= replacement
print("Updated rolelist:",changerole(rol**elist,1))
```

I am trying to run this quote, but it says TypeError: changerole() missing 1 required positional argument: 'replacement'

Comment: `replacement` is a function? because you call `replacement()`

Comment: This is not executable Python code due to multiple syntax errors

Comment: You should give examples that what you expected and what you found and the code where you defined 'rol' and 'elist'.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing 1 positional argument as in the def function you have provided 3, but in the print function you have only entered 2.

What you can do is, change this line

```
def changerole(role,roleindex,replacement):
```

To

```
def changerole(roleindex,replacement):
```